# Tool to create SQLXMLBulkLoad Schemas?

Tags: .net, xsd, sqlxml

SQLXMLBulkLoad requires schemas to be annotated with various attributes (e.g. sql:datatype) and some additional elements. Is there any tool that can enrich a schema with this information for at least some basic scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked a similar question and have done some researches.  It seems that there is not tool to create SQLXMLBulkLoad schema in the market.  I am trying to write one by myself.  Since the schema is a XML file, we can use LINQ to XML to insert the annotation information.

Comment: Well I started writing something myself too but I haven't gotten much further. Are you going to put something on CodePlex/GitHub/...? I can do that if you're interested but I never got past the first few unit tests.

Comment: @Frank de Groot - Schouten, I decide not to use SQLXMLBulkLoad any more for my project.  Instead I will used SQLBULKCOPY which is about 10 times faster for my dataset.